# How would I use django-userena but with no user on the URL

Tags: django, url, django-users

The standard django-userena URL's expect the user name to be on the URL:

```
/accounts/USER/  # for profile view
/accounts/USER/edit/ # to edit the profile
```

My user profiles are all going to be closed, so I'd rather my url's not include the user:

```
/accounts/ # would show the profile view (or signin if they aren't logged in)
/accounts/edit/ # to edit the profile
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming over their docs, it doesn't look like it. You will need to write your own urls/views for this.

Comment: Apparently as girasquid points out there is nothing built-in - primarily because they have hardcoded some paths in various places but also there are some other assumptions. Forked my own copy and have hacked it to work.